# Angular catchError in intercepter dialog not working

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I am trying to show Unauthenticated dialog and let user to click on the return to logging page when there is 403 error. Below code works fine but dialog is getting disappear immediately before user click on it to go back to logging page. Ideally Dialog should stay till user click on it. Any suggestions how I can fix it.

```
intercept(
req: HttpRequest<any>,
next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(req).pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.status === 401) {
      this.dialog.open(UnauthenticatedErrorDialogComponent);
    } else if (err.status === 403) {
      this.dialog.open(UnauthorizedErrorDialogComponent);
    }
   throw err;
  })
);
```

}

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Ideally in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)-

Comment: It might be because you are throwing error at the end, hence its closing it. Can you remove "throw err" code and try?